# Multiplying determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

> Let $A, B$ be two matrices. Let $\det(A)=4$, $\det(B)=2/3$. Find $\det(AB^{-1})$.

---

I already found that $\det(B^{-1})= 3/2$ as a determinant to the power of $-1$ equals $1$ over the determinant. I was just using one of the theorems in my text book that stated that

$$\det(B^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\det(B)}$$

Comment: How did you prove $\det(B^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\det(B)}$ without knowing $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$?

Comment: $3/2*4=6{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Does $\det(BB^{-1})=\det(I)=1$ vs. $\det(B)\det(B^{-1})=\det(B)\det(B)^{-1}=1$ hint you anything ?

Comment: There should be another theorem in your textbook that says $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$.

Comment: Ben Grossman, there is that theorem but it does not show me how to multiply the determinants when I only have the determinant values and not the matrices.

Comment: I do not understand why you think you can't use the mentioned theorem... We never needed the matrices themselves... for square matrices $A$ and $B$ you have $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$... period.  Same for square matrices $A$ and $C$ you have $\det(AC)=\det(A)\det(C)$... and for square matrices $A$ and $B^{-1}$ you have $\det(AB^{-1})=\det(A)\det(B^{-1})$...

Comment: @JbkPanda You don't need to know what the matrices are. That theorem tells you that the determinant of a product of two matrices - *whatever they may be* - is the product of the determinants. You don't know $A$ or $B$ here, but that doesn't matter. You want to know what $\det(AB^{-1})$ is numerically. That formula tells you that $\det(AB^{-1}) = \det(A)\det(B^{-1})$. You have each of the last two pieces.. put them together and solve.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has not clearly indicated their background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is known that $\det(XY) = \det(X)\dot\det(Y)$ and $\det(X^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\det(X)}$.

So, your question is $\det(AB^{-1}) = \frac{\det(A)}{\det(B)}=6$

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes a lot of sense.